# dynamically bind variable/parameter in Spark SQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

How to bind variable in Apache Spark SQL? For example:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM src WHERE col1 = ${VAL1}").collect().foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 16):

Spark SQL (as of 1.6 release) does not support bind variables.

Update: Spark 3.4 will have "parametrized SQL queries"
https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/38864

```scala
  spark.sql(
    sqlText = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date > :startDate LIMIT :maxRows",
    args = Map(
      "startDate" -> "DATE'2022-12-01'",
      "maxRows" -> "100"))
```

and similarly Dataframe API

```scala
def sql(sqlText: String, args: Map[String, String]): DataFrame
```

---

ps. What Ashrith is suggesting is not a bind variable.. You're constructing a string every time. Every time Spark will parse the query, create execution plan etc. Purpose of bind variables (in RDBMS systems for example) is to cut time on creating execution plan (which can be costly where there are a lot of joins etc). Spark has to have a special API to "parse" a query and then to "bind" variables. Spark does not have this functionality (as of today, Spark 1.6 release).

**Update 8/2018**: as of Spark 2.3 there are (still) no bind variables in Spark.

Answer (score 13):

I verified it in both **Spark shell 2.x** shell and **Thrift(beeline)** as well. I could able to bind a variable in Spark SQL query with `set` command.

**Query without bind variable:**

```
select count(1) from mytable;
```

**Query with bind variable (parameterized):**

> **1. Spark SQL shell**
>
> ```
>  set key_tbl=mytable; -- setting mytable to key_tbl to use as ${key_tbl}
>  select count(1) from ${key_tbl};
> ```
>
> **2. Spark shell**
>
> ```
> spark.sql("set key_tbl=mytable")
> spark.sql("select count(1) from ${key_tbl}").collect()
> ```

Both w/w.o bind params the query returns an identical result.

> Note:  **Don't give any quotes to the value of key** as it's table name here.

Let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: with val slqDF = spark.sql("select count(*) from Prd_IN_GeneralEvents where pdid like $'{id}'")   Same Error

Comment: those are NOT bind variables.

Comment: @Tagar  could you please explain why these are not bind variables ? Because f-strings doesn't seem the way to go

Comment: @neverMind please see my separate answer above why these are not bind variables. Bind variables has to be supported by a backend (Spark in this case). It's an industry term specific for RDBMS systems. Bind variables allow you to create a prepared version of an execution plan in the backend, and execute (multiple) times same prepared statement with (perhaps different values of the bind variables) without re-analyzing the query, re-creating execution plan (which can be costly). This is not supported by Spark. Just substituting a literal value into SQL text doesn't make it a bind variable.

Answer (score -2):

Pyspark

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM src WHERE col1 = {1} and col2 = {2}".format(VAL1,VAL2).collect().foreach(println)
```

Comment: This is, how you introduce SQL injection vulnerabilities into your applications. It is almost always wrong to insert some variables into an SQL statement without properly escaping them.