# Spark SQL - How do i set a variable within the query, to re-use throughout?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I'm trying to convert a query from T-SQL to Spark's SQL.
I've got 99% of the way, but we've made strong use of the DECLARE statement in T-SQL.

I can't seem to find an alternative in Spark SQL that behaves the same - that is, allows me to declare variables in the query itself, to be re-used in that query.

Example in T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @varA int
SET @varA = '4'
SELECT * FROM tblName where id = @varA;
```

How do i do the declaration of such a variable in Spark SQL? (I don't want to use string interpolation, unless necessary)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not supported in Spark SQL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755230/dynamically-bind-variable-parameter-in-spark-sql

Comment: Oh no :( Thank you! Guess I either hard code these values (yuck) or go string interpolation (which i guess is better than hard-coding). Odd feature to miss, but ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
sqlContext.sql("set id_value = 3")
sqlContext.sql("select * from country where id = ${id_value}").show()
```

[image]